# jquery load all rows editable table with dropdownlist inside

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I need load an editable table from jquery ajax call. Let user edit/update it, and then bulk insert/update to database. In this table, there is a column called Type. It's a dropdown list.  Loaded by original value, but can let user change it.
How should I add the dropdown from ajax call.

```
 success: function (returndata)
{
    if (returndata.ok) {
        var tbl = "<table id='tbl' border='1' class='table table-hover'><thead><tr style='text-align:center;'>"
        tbl += "<th>Name</th><th>Hours</th><th>Comment</th><th>Type</th></thead></table>"
        $("#Table").append(tbl);
        $.each(returndata.data, function (index, itemData) {
            var tbody = "<tr style='text-align:center;'><td><input id='txtName"+itemData.Id+"' style='width:70px;' type='text' value='"+itemData.Name+"'></td>"
            tbody +="<td><input id='txtHours"+itemData.Id+"' style='width:40px;' type='text' value='"+itemData.Hours+"'></td>"
            tbody +="<td><input id='txtComent"+itemData.Id+"' type='text' value='"+itemData.Comment+"'></td>"
            tbody +="<td><select id='ddlType"+itemData.Id+"'><option value=''>Select Type</option></td>"
        });
    }
    else {
        window.alert(' error : ' + returndata.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another global variable s and load s with all options. When load the table, I load all options first and then replace the selecteditem add "selected="selected" . Now it works. This may not be best practice. Please give me your suggestion.

```
var TypeOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["Type"]));
var s='<option value="">Select Type</option>';

for (var e=0; e < TypeOptions.length; e++)
{
    var lt =  TypeOptions[e];
    s += '<option value="'+lt["TypeId"]+'">'+lt["Type"]+' </option>';
}

success: function (returndata)
{
    if (returndata.ok) {
        var tbl = "<table id='tbl' border='1' class='table table-hover'><thead><tr style='text-align:center;'>"
        tbl += "<th>Name</th><th>Hours</th><th>Comment</th><th>Type</th></thead>"
        $("#Table").append(tbl);
        $.each(returndata.data, function (index, itemData) {
            var tbody = "<tr style='text-align:center;'><td><input id='txtName"+itemData.Id+"' style='width:70px;' type='text' value='"+itemData.Name+"'></td>"
            tbody +="<td><input id='txtHours"+itemData.Id+"' style='width:40px;' type='text' value='"+itemData.Hours+"'></td>"
            tbody +="<td><input id='txtComent"+itemData.Id+"' type='text' value='"+itemData.Comment+"'></td>"
            tbody +="<td><select id='ddlType"+itemData.Id+"'>"+ s +"</select></td></tr>"
            tbody = tbody.replace('<option value="'+itemData.TypeId+'">', '<option selected="selected" value="'+itemData.TypeId+'">');  
        });
        tbl += tbody+"</table>"
    }
    else {
        window.alert(' error : ' + returndata.message);
    }
}
```